# combined 2 different structure tables and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables employees and salaries the salaries table has multiple duplicate id's on it my question is how can i combined the employee and salaries table and removed its duplicate but i want the max salary to be displayed for that employee.

Employees table
[image]

Salaries table
[image]

Comment: Please give the table structure and sample data. It would be better if you could recreate tables in [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: i've uploaded the image of the structure of tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the definition of the `salaries` table (`from_date` & `to_date`) it's a [Slowly Changing Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_Changing_Dimension). Your data might look like this:

```
Emp_no  salary   from_date     to_date
  22     14000  2007-01-01  2008-03-31 -- or 2008-04-01
  22     16000  2008-04-01  2010-12-31 -- or 2011-01-01
  22     18000  2011-01-01  9999-12-31 -- or NULL
```

In that case you don't want the `MAX` salary but the current/latest salary.

In a SCD `to_date` is usually set to either a maximum date like `9999-12-31` or `3999-12-31` or `NULL`. To get the current salary you use following conditions:

```
WHERE to_date IS NULL 
or
WHERE to_date = DATE '9999-12-31' -- or whatever your max date is
or 
WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
```

To get the salary for any point in time:

```
WHERE whatever_date_you_want BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this. I created a fiddle demo with necessary columns.

```
select e.*, s.salary from
employees e
inner join
(
select emp_no,max(salary) as salary from salaries
group by emp_no
) s
on e.emp_no=s.emp_no
```

**See Fiddle demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5b67/5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you wanted.

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE LEFT JOIN SALARY ON EMPLOYEE.ID=SALARY.ID GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.ID
```